# How to visualizing what 3D convnets learn and display the output of multi-layers

Tags: python, tensorflow

I already have the 3D CNN model in **Python** and I visualized the output of the first layer. My question is: how to visualize the other layers? Anyone can help me, please.

Comment: When you say visualize, are you talking about what the model would look like with each layer and their inputs/outputs (similar to `model.summary()`? You can use `keras.utils.vis_utils.plot_model` to show that. The code would like something like: `keras.utils.vis_utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, to_file="/path/to/output/file")`. Or maybe the library here is what you're looking for? https://github.com/paulgavrikov/visualkeras (note these are two different visualization methods).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my question about how visualize the feature map? how to plot the images after each layer? how the images look after use filter in each layer but in 3D CNN.